# Transform and Send CSV file to WSO2 DSS service

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a CSV file. I want to send the data in CSV to database using a DSS service.

How can I use VFS transport for that? Or Do I need to use another mediator for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have a Data Service that inserts a record into your table.

Then a proxy that deals with the file, the proxy can use VFS to read the file, then a Smooks mediator to transform the CSV to XML.

From there the proxy can iterate over the records from the CSV file and send them to the dataservice.

Comment: Using https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-how-to-process-a-csv-file-using-the-smooks-mediator I could add smooks mediator